# How can you find out the version of xlC installed on AIX box

Tags: c++, compiler-construction, version, aix, xlc

So this should be quite simple but just want to see if I got it right.

I am trying to find out what version of xlC compiler is installed on AIX box.

I tried xlC -v/xlc --version which is not supported by the compiler.

I tried lslpp -L | grep xlC

I get following output but it confuses me (i am releatively new to UNIX world)

```
  xlC.adt.include            8.0.0.0    C     F    C Set ++ Application
  xlC.aix50.rte              8.0.0.0    C     F    C Set ++ Runtime for AIX 5.0
  xlC.cpp                    6.0.0.0    C     F    C for AIX Preprocessor
  xlC.msg.en_US.cpp          6.0.0.0    C     F    C for AIX Preprocessor
  xlC.msg.en_US.rte          8.0.0.0    C     F    C Set ++ Runtime
  xlC.rte                    8.0.0.0    C     F    C Set ++ Runtime
```

This is list on installed packages on box but whats the significance of listing .cpp file.

And which version is on my box?

6.0 or 8.0

Thanks

Answer (score 19, accepted):

Try `xlC -qversion`

Answer (score 1):

Try `lslpp -l | grep -i vacpp` and check for lines about the C/C++ Compiler:

```
vacpp.cmp.core            9.0.0.11  APPLIED    IBM XL C/C++ Compiler
vacpp.cmp.core             9.0.0.0  COMMITTED  IBM XL C/C++ Compiler
```

This means I have 9.0 installed with a subsequent PTF added.
My corresponding xlc version information looks like this:

```
% xlc -qversion=verbose
IBM XL C/C++ Enterprise Edition for AIX, V9.0
Version: 09.00.0000.0011
Driver Version: 09.00(C/C++) Level: 090810
C Front End Version: 09.00(C/C++) Level: 090730
C++ Front End Version: 09.00(C/C++) Level: 090730
High-Level Optimizer Version: 09.00(C/C++) and 11.01(Fortran) Level: 090812
Low-Level Optimizer Version: 09.00(C/C++) and 11.01(Fortran) Level: 090902
```

Also the xlc/rte entries you found are for the C/C++ Runtime, which will depend on the OS version and are not as closely linked to the compiler version.  This source of confusion is also mentioned in the link below.

See http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21652272

Answer (score 0):

```
cc –qversion or xlc -qversion or xlC –qversion
```